# Receiving commercial / public-safety on a general-coverage HAM transceiver

Tags: transceiver, fm, equipment-operation, icom, bandwidth

I have an ICOM-7100 that I've installed in my mobile as my primary (nay, only) HAM transceiver; and I'm trying to avoid wasting a ton of space in my vehicle (not to mention money) for a proper scanner, or for a CB¹, to achieve fuller coverage of the available spectrum-space. Unfortunately, some poking around frequency-listing websites reveals that a lot of the interesting non-HAM action happens over “NFM” — which I finally ascertained² to be a 2.5kHz-deviation FM mode used by commercial / emergency-services devices.

I'd really like to scan across such channels without installing yet-more equipment in my passenger compartment; and yet I can't find any mention whatsoever of FM deviation in my ICOM-7100 manual. Is there any way for me to intelligibly receive (or for that matter, transmit) 2.5kHz-deviation FM signals with my transceiver?

---

¹ Not very related, but to my annoyance, it looks like there's no MARS/CAP modification for the 7100 that covers the CB “11-meter band”, 26.965–27.405MHz. I might *have* to install a second damn box to talk to truckers. Bah.

² It also looks like a huge set of the interesting frequencies are digital “Project 25,” P25, mode; I'm just assuming there's no hope of receiving those on a HAM transceiver. :P

Comment: This site is all about creating a database of questions with answers.  Please don't combine questions, because that breaks the way the site works.  Your other questions should be asked separately, if they haven't been asked already.

Comment: Those weren't really questions (I wouldn't ask for CAP mods on a stack-exchange!), just conversational comments. (I participate heavily on various SEs and SO; but if such a conversational style of question is unwelcome on this particular site, I'll try and moderate my approach!)

Comment: Here's [a similar question](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/117/can-a-licensed-ham-use-or-modify-cb-equipment-to-work-the-10-meter-amateur-bands) to your question about CB.  Regarding P25, hams do have P25 repeaters set up, but I believe they use repurposed commercial radios to do so.  I'm not sure if there is such a thing as a scanner that can receive P25.

Comment: There are a lot of sites telling how to do the MARS mods on the 7100:  https://www.google.com/search?q=ICOM-7100+mods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your original question, according to page 5-6 of the [IC-7100 Advanced Instructions](http://www.icomamerica.com/en/downloads/DownloadDocument.aspx?Document=632) document, to receive "narrow" FM of 2.5 kHz deviation, select FILTER2 or FILTER3.

Comment: Ahhah! I was mis-led by the “Passband widths for FM … are fixed, and cannot be set!” Well-spotted, my man.